# Freeing memory after passing value causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, free

When I free `normalizedWord` in `foo` after passing it to `AddElement` I get a segfault when trying to do a strcmp with `key`. Without freeing, there's no issue, other than a gigantic memory leak. Any idea what might be going on here?

```
foo(char* word)
{
    char* normalizedWord = (char*)(malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(normalizedWord, word);

    Normalize(normalizedWord);
    int result = AddElement(dict->hashTable, normalizedWord);

    free(normalizedWord);
    return result;
}

AddElement(HashTable *hashTable, const char *key)
{
    if (0 == hashTable->elements[hashIndex])
    {
        // Add new element
        hashTable->elements[hashIndex] = CreateElement(key);
    }
    else
    {
        // Search for existing or Add new element
        Element* current = hashTable->elements[hashIndex];

        /* ERROR HERE... */
        while (0 != strcmp(current->key, key))
        {
            if (NULL == current->next)
            {
                current->next = CreateElement(key);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

Element* CreateElement(const char* key)
{
    Element* element;

    if (NULL == (element = malloc(sizeof(element))))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    element->key = (char*) malloc(strlen(key) + 1);
    strcpy(element->key, key);

    return element;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Normalize` does something bad ?

Comment: The following pieces of information are missing: 1. Implementation of function `Normalize`. 2. Call to function `foo`. 3. Declaration, instantiation and initialization of global variable `dict`.

Comment: In `CreateElement()`, you need to set the `next` pointer of the new element to NULL... `AddElement()` is probably trying to move past the end of the list to an invalid node.

Comment: A couple of coding suggestions: 1. Try to avoid the use of global variables where possible. 2. Get rid of that `if (constant value == something)` convention. True, it was "invented" in order to protect you from using `=` instead of `==` by mistake, but it just makes the code a lot less readable. Protect yourself by making sure that you use `==`. 3. On the same issue, take the assignment out of that `if (NULL == (element = ...)))` statement.

Comment: 4. Avoid casting the return-value of `malloc`. 5. Why are you using `if (0 == hashTable->elements[hashIndex])` when you have proper comparisons with `NULL` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: @barakmanos What global variable are you talking about?

Comment: Variable `dict` (used in function `foo`).

Comment: @barakmanos That's required for this implementation as a part of the provided API, not much I can do about that.

Comment: No problem, it was merely a suggestion ("where possible").

Comment: @barakmanos tips appreciated, thanks for code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I could see is that the `element->next` is not initialized while creating an element. It is clear that `next` is not a static member, hence when first element is added, its `next` value will contain garbage. And because of this, `current` is assigned some garbage value by following section of code:

```
else
{
    current = current->next;
}
```

which caused out of segment memory access in strcmp();

Adding `element->next=NULL;` in `CreateElement()` function may fix this segmentation fault.

Comment: This definitely is the problem, as pointed out by Dmitri in the comments above. Will select your as the correct answer for now since Dmitri did not submit an answer. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the uninitialized `element->next` that Illuminatus pr pointed out, you have a problem with the *size* of the memory you are allocating. The statement

```
Element* element = malloc(sizeof(element));
```

allocates enough memory *for one pointer*, not for the actual element. What you need to write is something like this:

```
Element* element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
```

The only difference is the additional star, which can make the difference between allocating eight bytes or a kilobyte.

Comment: That explains some of what I've been seeing in valgrind.